# Track two processes (checker)

Tags: vbscript

I did some code to test one process and a list of processes. I did something myself, but I do not know where to set up another process. Please look at the image below and the code. I hope I wrote it clearly.

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim arrProcesses : arrProcesses = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Project\list_processes.txt").ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Dim colProcesses : Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery(_
                                      "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & Join(arrProcesses, "' OR Name = '") & "'")
If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Command = "Command 1"
    WshShell.Run Command
Else
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Command = "Command 2"
    WshShell.Run Command
End If
```

[image]

Comment: How do "Process 1" and "list of processes" translate to boolean values?

Comment: It works now if the script finds at least one process from the list, then it executes the command. I need the script to be executed when two processes are found (one specific and any one of the It works now if the script finds at least one process from the list, then it executes the command. I need the script to be executed when two processes are found (one specific and any one of the list processes)

Answer (score 1):

Add another lookup for your specific process:

```
pname = "Process 1"
Set p = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='" & pname & "'")

If p.Count > 0 And colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
    'do something
Else
    'do other
End If
```

Make sure "Process 1" is not in `arrProcesses` if your condition is "process 1 and any other process from the list are running".

Comment: thank you
It works, but when process 1 is true and the process list is false, the command is executed in the same way (Command 1)

Comment: I doubt that. Please provide evidence.

Comment: I a little change a code and got the right result.
Thanks for the help. Please tell me if you need to put the code in this site to other people